# C# WPF IChangeTracking IRevertibleChangeTracking implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, change-tracking

I Have WPF Page which has one Datagridview with 
radio buttons columns (Requested,Proposed,Confirmed,Cancelled)
and a Search Button, 
On clicking that it shows following data in Datagridview 
about 5 Rows.
It could be more than 1000 records or 1500 record in live environment.

```
Index Last Name First Name    Requested Proposed Confirmed Cancelled
----------------------------  --------- -------- --------- ---------
1     B2        R2            0         0        1         0
2     d         d             0         0        1         0
3     d         d             0         0        1         0
4     d         d             0         0        1         0
5     SG0019    SG0019        0         0        0         0
```

Now Case 1:
I want only modified rows out of these 5 rows
like for first record user changes the status as follow
and clicks on Save button then i sould send only one record or
data related to index 1 or changed record

```
Index Last Name First Name    Requested Proposed Confirmed Cancelled
----------------------------  --------- -------- --------- ---------
1     B2        R2            0         0        0         1
```

Now Case 2:

If User modifies only two rows like following

```
Original Data

Index Last Name First Name    Requested Proposed Confirmed Cancelled
----------------------------  --------- -------- --------- ---------
1     B2        R2            0         0        1         0
2     d         d             0         0        1         0
3     d         d             0         0        1         0
4     d         d             0         0        1         0
5     SG0019    SG0019        0         0        0         0

Modififed Data

Step 1

Index Last Name First Name    Requested Proposed Confirmed Cancelled
----------------------------  --------- -------- --------- ---------
1     B2        R2            0         0        0         1-------- Changed Status
2     d         d             0         0        0         1-------- Changed Status

Step 2
Index Last Name First Name    Requested Proposed Confirmed Cancelled
----------------------------  --------- -------- --------- ---------
1     B2        R2            0         0        1         0-------- Back to Original
2     d         d             0         0        0         1-------- Changed Status
```

So I want only second record that is modified even though record one is 
modified but it is back to its original state or value
so how can I achive these two things
using IChangeTracking or irevertiblechangetracking.